# xsl - select node by child

Tags: xslt, select

I have a problem selecting just elements of an xml, which contain a specific child node. Asumme the following part of an xml:

```
<root>
<Navision.Buchungen>
    <Saldo>-110867.7500</Saldo>
    <Navision.Kontostruktur>
        <Bereich>1</Bereich>
    </Navision.Kontostruktur>
</Navision.Buchungen>
<Navision.Buchungen>
    <Saldo>-3082585.2100</Saldo>
    <Navision.Kontostruktur>
        <Bereich>2</Bereich>
    </Navision.Kontostruktur>
</Navision.Buchungen>
...
</root>
```

Now I have an xsl part like this to get the sum of 'Saldo':

```
<xsl:variable name="FACT0" select="sum(//root/Navision.Buchungen/Saldo)"/>
```

But how can I select just the Saldo for 'Bereich' 1 for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this XPath:

```
//root/Navision.Buchungen[Navision.Kontostruktur/Bereich = 1]/Saldo
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//root/Navision.Buchungen[Navision.Kontostruktur/Bereich = 1]/Saldo
```

**Edited:**
oh already posted.

For further problems you can use one of the online testbeds like [this one](http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm). And of course good manuals like [those from w3schools, also with testbeds for xsl](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)